# How to dynamically use css with a sprite

Tags: asp.net, sprite

I have a sprite I created dynamically.  I understand to show this as animation I need to change the offsets for the position of this image.  I read you put this into a CSS file.  How do I dynamically create this CSS and use it dynamically using asp.net and C#?

So far I change these offsets using AJAX, a timer and response.write the DIV. But the image appears to flicker.  So, I am hoping that by using CSS it will eliminate this flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX you could simply return the offset x and y positions, and only update the element's style.

Recreating the entire element will remove the current element from the DOM, and add a new one in place (which causes the flickering).

Using a library such as jQuery you could do:

```
$.get("/ajaxurl", function(data){
    $(".myelement").css("background-position", data.x + "px " + data.y + "px;");
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for replying.  Your reply makes sense now i am trying to implement this.  I curse the day i decided not to use JavaScript and concentrate on managed code. How i can i invoke this method from code behind using a timer?  I appreciate this may look like a daft question.  I am looking for examples via Google as i type but cannot find anything yet...

Comment: It was a daft reply from me.  Quite easy really.  I just need to link the web method to a timer now...

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Look into the use of `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`